# How to differentiate with respect to sum of variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If f is a function of x,y,z. How do I differentiate f wrt x+y+z?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! We usually would like to see an example function, with proper *Mathematica* syntax, properly formatted in code blocks. Please edit your post with more information! As it is, mathematically, this operation isn't really well-defined until you've specified a complete coordinate transformation (i.e. x, y, z goes to x1, x2, x3).

Comment: Substitute t:= x+y+z.  ;-)